# usage of the word "quite" in context

Tags: meaning

Here goes:

> Quite how much we should value consistency is an interesting issue.

I have looked up all meaning of "quite", but still puzzled by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, ***quite*** is synonymous to ***exactly***.

> "Exactly how much we should value consistency is an interesting issue."

---

Quite takes a couple of meanings depending of context and whether you negate it or not. But it always takes the form as a quantifier.

> *"He **is not quite** capable of the task"*
>
> > He may be capable, yes. But not as much as we would like him to be for completing this task. Not quite capable.
>
> "He **is quite** capable of the task"
>
> > He is very capable of this task. Even more capable than required for completing this task.
>
> "I am **quite** sure, that he is capable."
>
> > I am very sure, that he is capable.
>
> "I am **not quite** sure, that he is capable."
>
> > "I am not so sure, whether he is capable or not. Maybe he is but I am doubt."
>
> "They told me that I was **quite** mistaken"
>
> > They told me that I was very mistaken
>
> "I did not **quite** see what happened"
>
> > "I did not exactly see what happened"